# Passing Texbox string to countif in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

Trying to get an Array to work with Formula Countif, but cant manage to get the countif right, can anyone give me a pointer please? I have a userform with 5 textboxes on it add a search word in 1 or maybe 2 i wanted them to use the countif formula.

Sorry if this seems simple to you guys im still a newbie.

```
Worksheets("Questions").Activate
Dim WordArray As Variant
WordArray = Array(UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch1.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch2.Value, 
UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch3.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch4.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch5.Value)

ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Formula = "=CountIfs(B2:E2), WordArray"

LastPopulatedRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("F2: " & "F" & LastPopulatedRow).FillDown
```

@Bigben do you mean like this??

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Formula = "=CountIfs(B2:E2, {WordArray})"
```

Comment: `WordArray` should not fall inside the quotes, and you need to `Join` the values with a comma and then enclose the resulting string in braces `{}`.

Comment: @BigBen I tried the above and many many other versions but still not working, the quotations get added on their own by VBA

Comment: Am i getting closer?

Comment: See how the variable `WordArray` falls within the quotes in `"=CountIfs(B2:E2, {WordArray})"`? It should not. It needs concatenated with `&`, but you'll also need to `Join`, as you can't concatenate an array to a string.

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance BigBen, however i found it i cannot use countif as there is a 255 character limit.  Many thanks, Mark.